# Filter rows in csv file (pgfplots)

Tags: csv, latex, tikz, pgfplots

I create a plot (pgfplots) with the following command.
I would like to filter some of the rows in `myFile.csv` according to some conditions. E.g value in col `myZcol > 3` or `myZcol=3`. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw=none}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\footnotesize
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=purple,mark=o]  table [x=myXCol,y=myYCol,col sep=comma, dashed, ] {myFile.csv}; %    
\legend{ser1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Assuming `myFile.csv` is -

```
myXCol,myYCol,myZCol
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I would like the plot to grab only the records where `myZCol<7`, that is only the first 2 records.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: If you preprocess your data e.g. with Python, you could set values which you don't want to display to `nan` (just as regular String). PGFPlots understands this and leaves them out.

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199396/84434) might also help you